# Passing local variable in python sshClient command

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I am using python 2.7.6 for scripting

problem statement:-
In my script, I have extracted my applicationId in variable say 'appid' at runtime
now I have to pass this as variable in SSHClient command to be executed in remote server, in cmd below

```
ssh_idb = SSHClient(cfg_cluster_ip)
ssh_idb.login_with_password(username=idb_ssh_user,password=idb_ssh_password)
cmd ='ps -ef | grep "Admin|$appid"'
out, err, code = ssh_idb.execute_sudo_command(["%s" % cmd])
print out
```

It returns blank output [expected value is not being passed in cmd and shell doesn't returns any data]
Is there a way to pass local variable value in cmd dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very unclear. Do you mean `appid` is a local variable in your Python script? If so, you need to pass it to the command string:

```
cmd ='ps -ef | grep "Admin|%s"' % appid
```

Comment: yes, that solves my problem! thanks. Also, we could able to figure out another way using 
cmd = "ps -ef | grep 'CA|" + str(appid) +  "'"